# how to find the jobs run by each local users

Tags: command-line, bash, top, ps

I am interested in finding what applications/scripts are executed by each linux user.

I can find the number of jobs run by a specific user with the following command

```
ps -u <USERNAME> -U <USERNAME>
```

However it shows the jobs of a specific provided user whereas I want it for all users or all local users.

E.g. the following command count the number of jobs by each user

```
ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c
```

I want a similar command but i want to see all the processes run by a user. Thanks.

@update E.g.

```
Uname    PID   CMD    
user1    1010  systemd    
user1    1011  sshd    
user1    1012  bash   
user1    1013  ps    
user2    1020  systemd    
user2    1021  sshd    
user2    1022  bash    
user2    1023  ps    
user2    1024  tux    
user2    1025  python   
user2    1026  python    
.......    
.......    
.......
```

Comment: can you give an example of the output that you would like to see?

Comment: question updated by giving an example output I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you only need a loop over the user names.
Write a shell script, say, `ps_users.sh` like

```
 #!/bin/bash
 
 NUSERPROC=$(ps -eo user=|sort|uniq)
 
 for user in ${NUSERPROC} ; do
     echo "========= ${user} ========="
     ps -u ${user} -U ${user}
 done
```

(of course, do not include the line numbers) and then run `sh ./ps_users.sh`.
Adapt the contents of the loop to cater your needs.

Comment: Amazing, thanks :)

Comment: You can get rid of line numbers to make it copy paste for lazy people like me :)

Comment: I did so. I actually added them to reference lines by numbers, but then it was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

To list cron jobs that belong to a **specific user**, run the following command:

```
sudo crontab –u username –l
```

Replace username with the actual **username** you’re viewing.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP was about cron jobs, but rather all jobs running.